# Nodemailer not working on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nodemailer

I am EC2 instance up and running , I wanted to integrate nodemailer in my application. Following the https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer I was able to send email from my localhost. When the same code I integrated on `EC2` instance I am getting `Invalid login error` . Sometime gmail blocks login from other application and send confirm mail to the inbox. I didnt get any such mail also. Do I need to enable some port on `EC2` instance or I can use `nodemailer` at all on EC2 instance. Please suggest

Comment: [Previous question and I had the same problem, it's turning on access to less secure apps][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/635139/how-to-fix-send-mail-authorization-failed-534-5-7-14

Answer (score 2):

**No** need to enable aws ses service

**Open port** :  465 on aws(e2c) instance in outbound section.

**Test if port really opened** : with nmap command `nmap 14.247.74.33`.

**Note** : do not proceed until you see open ports like

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-08-15 19:01 IST
Nmap scan report for 14.247.74.33
Host is up (0.058s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
80/tcp open  http
465    open
```

**Simple** nodemailer configuration works

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: EMAIL_ID,
        pass: EMAIL_PASSOWRD,
    },
});
```

[Full example code](https://gist.github.com/pawarvijay/047ff855e504ff443374c47ec25c1d1e)

Comment: Well, still this configuration gives `QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:213:19)` error.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail is not a production SMTP service. Configure nodemailer to send mail from a production mailer, such as [AWS Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/). [Like gmail, SES is a "well-known service" in nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-wellknown#supported-services). There's [a great example of using SES in the nodemailer README](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#use-a-transport-plugin).